# tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str in Pandas dataframe(during iteration of rows)

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes, where `id` column is string:

`df` data frame

```
         id     entity
60251   BG*155  People
42105   BG*110  General Company
58607   BG*1    General Company
33760   BG*11   People
```

df_temp_correct

```
      id    direct_neighbor other_neighbor  
0   BG*11       1.0               0.0
1   BG*112      0.0               0.0
2   BG*49       0.0               0.0
3   BG*56       1.0               0.0
4   BG*71       0.0               1.0
5   BG0         1.0               0.0
6   BG0         0.0               0.0
```

In my case both dataframe are much more bigger and they have common `id` values. Other columns are different and data frame have different size.

What I want to do: if id of data frames match, then i want to add value of `df_temp_correct` to the row from `df`( to the row of `df` if `id` of `df` match `id` of  `df_temp_correct`)

Here is the code:

```
df['val_12'] = 0
for row in df.iterrows():
    # look for corresponding rows in df_temp_correct dataframe 
    # that matches id of current row of df1
    val_df = df_temp_correct.loc[df_temp_correct['id'] == row['id']]
    # if id matched in df_temp_correct then it will return non-empty
    if not val_df.empty:
         # assign corresponding row of df1 with first value 
         # of temp which where id matched
        df.loc[index, 'val_12'] = val_df['val_12'].values[0]
```

But i receive the following error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I correct it?

**EDIT:**

Expected result:

`df` data frame

```
         id     entity             direct_neighbor
60251   BG*155  People                   0  
42105   BG*110  General Company          0
58607   BG*1    General Company          0
33760   BG*11   People                   1
```

As you seem `'id' BG*11`matches, so I add the values of `direct_neighbor` to the id column if df data frame. Otherwise, if id's don't match, then add a value 0.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for the given example?

Comment: @akilat90 added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does not answer the question in the title, I suggest the use of  `pd.merge` for a task of this nature.

Creating two dataframes. Note that `B1` is common to both.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'], 'entity': ['people', 
'general', 'people', 'general']})

df
Out[35]: 
    entity  id
0   people  B1
1  general  B2
2   people  B3
3  general  B4

df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['B1', 'B5', 'B6'], 'direct_neighbor' : 
[1,0,0], 'other_neighbor':[0,1,0]})

df_temp
Out[36]: 
   direct_neighbor  id  other_neighbor
0                1  B1               0
1                0  B5               1
2                0  B6               0
```

Merging the two dataframes using `'id'`

```
x = pd.merge(df, df_temp, how = 'outer', on = 'id')

x
Out[28]: 
    entity  id  direct_neighbor  other_neighbor
0   people  B1              1.0             0.0
1  general  B2              NaN             NaN
2   people  B3              NaN             NaN
3  general  B4              NaN             NaN
4      NaN  B5              0.0             1.0
5      NaN  B6              0.0             0.0
```

A set-like operation

```
y = pd.merge(df, x)

y
Out[30]: 
    entity  id  direct_neighbor  other_neighbor
0   people  B1              1.0             0.0
1  general  B2              NaN             NaN
2   people  B3              NaN             NaN
3  general  B4              NaN             NaN
```

replacing `NaN`s with `0`

```
z = y.fillna(0)

z
Out[32]: 
    entity  id  direct_neighbor  other_neighbor
0   people  B1              1.0             0.0
1  general  B2              0.0             0.0
2   people  B3              0.0             0.0
3  general  B4              0.0             0.0
```

Dropping the unnecessary column

```
z = z.drop('other_neighbor',1)

z
Out[34]: 
    entity  id  direct_neighbor
0   people  B1              1.0
1  general  B2              0.0
2   people  B3              0.0
3  general  B4              0.0
```